# Convert dataframe values to 1D list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
V
Out[58]: 

     P1 P2 P3 

V1   a  b  c  
V2   f  g  h  
V3   k  l  m
```

I want to store them all in a list L such that:

```
L=[a,b,c,f,g,h,k,l,m]
```

iterating from 1 row to another. Any idea how to go about it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access the `.values` attribute, reshape, and convert to list using `ndarray.tolist`:

```
df.values.reshape(-1,).tolist()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'k', 'l', 'm']
```

Another would be `stack`ing followed by a direct `tolist` call:

```
df.stack().tolist()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'k', 'l', 'm']
```

Comment: @DChy No worries.

Answer (score 4):

Using `tolist` and `sum`

```
sum(df.values.tolist(),[])
Out[65]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'k', 'l', 'm']
```

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) is convenient for this:

```
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   ['f', 'g', 'h'],
                   ['k', 'l', 'm']],
                  columns=['P1', 'P2', 'P3'],
                  index=['V1', 'V2', 'V3'])

res = list(chain.from_iterable(df.values))

# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'k', 'l', 'm']
```

Comment: It's better to use `chain.from_iterable(df.values)`, so you don't have to unpack the lists.

Comment: No need for `dis`, just `df = pd.concat([df] * 100000)` and do a couple of timeit tests and you'll understand.